# Riemannian metric over moduli space of Riemann spheres with n punctures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

In the paper `Tessellations of moduli spaces and the mosaic operad' by Devadoss (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9807010.pdf), on page 5-6, the author identifies hyperbolic planar tree space (or the compactification of moduli space of $\mathbb{RP}^1$ with n punctures $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{0}^n(\mathbb{R})}$) with the space of all ideal $n$-polygons on the Poincare disk with $k$ marked diagonals for some $k$.

He then claims that "this perspective naturally gives a Riemann metric to $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{0}^n(\mathbb{R})}$" and it really escapes me what this Riemannian metric actually is.

Can some one explain and/or give reference to the description of this metric? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do the quotation marks end in your second sentence?

Comment: oops, edited to indicate where the quotation ends. thanks for catching that!